# Newbie needing help writing a test class for an invocable method

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, invocable-method

With a lot of help from this forum and the developer forum, I got my first invocable method to work but now I am stuck on writing the test class for it.

Here's my invocable method and the attempt at a test class:

```
global class CreatedDateWithinBusinessHours {
        @InvocableMethod(label = 'Created Date is within BH' description = 'Check if flow record Created Date is within business hours')
            public static List<Results> execute(List<Requests> requestList) {
           
            // Get the default business hours
            BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true];
            
            // Pass the Created Date Time of the flow Record
            Datetime targetTime = requestList[0].inputCreatedDateTime;

            // Boolean that returns true if date time is within Business hours
            Boolean isWithin = BusinessHours.isWithin(bh.id, targetTime);

            // Results object that holds the return values
            Results response = new Results();

            //Add the return values to the Results object
            response.outputMember = isWithin;

            //Wrap the Results object in a List container 
            List<Results> responseWrapper = new List<Results> ();
            responseWrapper.add(response);
            return responseWrapper;
    }

    global class Requests {
        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Created Date Time' description = 'Created Date of the Flow record' required = false)
           global Datetime inputCreatedDateTime;
        
    }
    global class Results {
        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Within Business Hours' description = 'Boolean that returns true if the Created Date is within Business Hours' required = true)
        public Boolean outputMember;
    }
}
```

```
@isTest
private class CDwithinBusinessHoursTest {
    static testMethod void validateCDBusinessHours() {
       
        Case  c = new Case ();
         
        Datetime recordCD = c.CreatedDate;
       
          insert c; 
        
        List<Datetime> requestList = new List<Datetime>();
        requestList.add(recordCD);
       
        Test.startTest();
         
        //Getting this error here: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void execute(List<Datetime>) from the type CreatedDateWithinBusinessHours
        CreatedDateWithinBusinessHours.execute(requestList);
        
           Test.stopTest();
        
        //Variable does not exist: outputMember             
           System.assert(outputMember);
       
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nicolai. Good job on getting it to work. My first invocables were tough, too. | Look at your `execute` method again and see what it is expecting: a `List<Requests>`.  Then look in your test class and see what you are sending to the `execute` method.